# OCR with the Tesseract interface

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

How do you OCR an tiff file using Tesseract's interface in c#?
Currently I only know how to do it using the executable.

Comment: can you please guide me how you managed to using Tesseract in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The source code seemed to be geared for an executable, you might need to rewire stuffs a bit so it would build as a DLL instead. I don't have much experience with Visual C++ but I think it shouldn't be too hard with some research. My guess is that someone might have had made a library version already, you should try Google.

Once you have tesseract-ocr code in a DLL file, you can then import the file into your C# project via Visual Studio and have it create wrapper classes and do all the marshaling stuffs for you. If you can't import then [DllImport](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/c__and_api.aspx) will let you call the functions in the DLL from C# code.

Then you can take a look at the original executable to find clues on what functions to call to properly OCR a tiff image.

Answer (score 40):

Take a look at [tessnet](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)

Comment: This is better than P/Invoking it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

C# program launches tesseract.exe and then reads the output file of tesseract.exe.

```
Process process = Process.Start("tesseract.exe", "out");
process.WaitForExit();
if (process.ExitCode == 0)
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText("out.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I discovered today that [EMGU](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation) now includes a Tesseract wrapper.  While the number of unmanaged dlls of the opencv lib might seem a little daunting, it's nothing that a quick copy to your output directory won't cure.  From there the actual OCR process is as simple as three lines:

```
Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "tessdata"), "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);
this.ocr.Recognize(clip);
optOCR.Text = this.ocr.GetText();
```

"robomatics" put together [a very nice youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kjdu8SjEtG0) that demonstrates a simple but effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft

Our [OCR module supports Tesseract](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/ocr) and if that proves to not be good enough, you can upgrade to a better engine and just change one line of code (we provide a common interface to multiple OCR engines).