# Tesseract OCR in C#

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OCR with the Tesseract interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328/ocr-with-the-tesseract-interface)

Just wondering if anyone has got a sample project or compliled dll of the tesseract ocr engine running in C#? I have tried going through the tessnet2 demo ([here](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)) but for some reason, I can't install the C++ stuff in my current VS2008 installation so can't build it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not helpfull anymore, but I just had a play with Tessnet2 and it worked fine. All it required was the correct tessdata folder. There are links from the Tessnet site to get them.